# Retrieving SpannableStringBuilder string as an array

Tags: android, text-processing, spannablestring

I am facing some problem trying to get Array of String from SpannableStringBuilder. I have tried mapping positions using TextWatcher and getSelection() but, it seemed to have complicated things. In my actual code I have ArrayList to store this.

Let's take an example of this image:
[image]

Now here's a further breakdown of my requirement. I want to get add a text into an ArrayList if:

- it seperated by ImageSpan or
- List item if it doesn't start with ImageSpan or
- List item if it doesn't End with ImageSpan

The final Array should look like ["a","b","c"]. I haven't been able to figure this out for few days. Is there any possible wait to check if there is ImageSpan within SpannableStringBuilder? Any helps of suggestions will be appreciated.